# Hiding a vocabulary from certain Drupal users

Tags: drupal, hide, vocabulary

I want hide a particular vocabulary from users other than admins. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_hide

You may also want to listen to Lullabot's podcast on taxonomy. (the video is a bit long in the tooth, it may not apply)

http://www.lullabot.com/podcasts/podcast-48-taxonomy-taxonomy-taxonomy